# Short-circuit rating in a photovoltaic DC combiner box

Tags: dc, protection, short-circuit, solar-energy

I am working on a large-scale, grid-connected solar power plant using DC combiner boxes and central inverters.

[image: Here is a simple diagram this]

I am new to photovoltaics but I don't find enough information on DC short-circuit protection on the internet. I am trying to understand:

- Should I place a circuit breaker inside the DC combiner box?
- How much should the breaking capacity of this circuit breaker be, and how should I calculate it?

Comment: Please draw a schematic or block diagram of what you are proposing.

Answer (score 2):

Quick illustration:

[image]

Suppose you wire N PV strings in parallel (N=3 above), each string having short circuit current Isc.

Cables should be chosen for this Isc.

However if one of the strings shorts, all the other strings wired in parallel will dump their Isc into the shorted one. Current is represented by arrows on the illustration. So the cable to that shorted string will carry (N-1) Isc, for which it is not rated, so it will melt, connectors will probably catch fire, and if the short is inside a panel, the other panels on that string will also receive (N-1) Isc reverse current.

Therefore each string needs a circuit breaker, and it should be located where the cables to the strings join each other. That's probably the "DC combiner box". Cables between that and the inverter, and the inverter's PV DC input should be rated to the sum of Isc of all paralleled strings.

In this example case, the circuit breaker for the shorted string (on the right) will trip due to 2*Isc current, whereas the others will not blow, because they only carry Isc current.

Breakers current rating should be chosen a bit above Isc (so they do not trip during normal use) and of course below the current rating of the cables, to make sure they do trip and protect the cables if a short occurs.

Fuses are also OK.

Breakers must be rated at least for the full open circuit voltage, and **they must be rated for DC**. AC breakers rely on AC current turning off 100-120 times per second, but DC does not turn off, so it is much harder to stop an electric arc with DC. Breakers designed for DC take special measures to extinguish the arc, like much wider contact spacing, etc. This also applies to all switches, you cannot use switches rated for AC in a high voltage DC application.

Note PV panels naturally have limited output current, so if there is only one string in parallel, breakers are not required (but they are convenient, to use as switches). The problem comes from the N-1 strings dumping their current into the string that has a short circuit and overloading it.

Comment: often fuses are used as trips are rare and single use protectors (like fuses) are cheaper.

Comment: @bobflux Thanks for your detailed explanation. I took the liberty of using your image and making some changes on it to bettr explain myquestion.
This DC box doesn't recieve any AC short circuit current for the grid? Since this is grid-tied power plant, shouldn't this box be protection against AC short circuit coming for the grid and passing through switchgears and transformer and inverter?

Comment: Breakers and fuses rated for DC normally also work on AC. The rest depends on your inverter, if the DC is isolated or not. You should check your local code for specifics, especially the type of RCD

Answer (score 1):

Every solar panel I have ever seen had a maximum fuse rating in the datasheet. Usually this can be found on the label on the panel also. When you combine strings in a combiner box you will be OK if you fuse each string separately with a fuse of this rating.

If you only have one or two strings you don't need a fuse. Three or more then you do.

Last time I checked, it was difficult to find breakers with a high enough DC voltage rating for grid tied PV strings. It is not too bad if you can keep under 250 V. But above 250 V it seemed to me that fuses were the only option.

Comment: Thank you, So the DC Combiner box must only be protected against DC short circuits? As it is a grid-tied power plant, doesn't any AC short circuit current enter the DC box?

Comment: I have no experience with large systems. But with small systems, there is no consideration of AC being present on the DC side of the inverter. Please note that the DC fuse (or breaker) will also blow (or trip) on AC current. Also note that the inverter will be connected to the grid through an AC breaker. That breaker will trip if a large AC fault current flows.

Comment: You should definitely spend some time reading the documentation for all the equipment you are planning to use. Some of these issues may be covered.